# How to make console menu?

Tags: c#

So I ask for this, beacous I can´t find the code anywhere I looked for it. 
I ask how i can make simple console menu. So the console show some options like a b c. User types in console a and option behind a shows. Like calculator when user type a console writes "pleas type number 1" then "pleas type number 2" and the console divide the two numbers and shows same menu like on beginning. Thank anyone who is going to help me.

Comment: Here is example https://github.com/nim/Console.Menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Console class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx)
The code may be like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("a b c d=exit");
while (true)
{
    var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (key.KeyChar == 'd')
        break;
    else if (new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'}.Contains(key.KeyChar))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} pressed", key.KeyChar));
    else
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} is not valid", key.KeyChar));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can i chage the code after else when you not pressed key a b c so it gonna say you did not choose valid option

Comment: I have changed the code to support invalid keys

Answer (score -1):

This is working code that I have tried.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Menu();
        }

        static void Menu()
        {
            double l_dblAnswer = 0;
            double l_dblRes = 0;
            string numbers = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Select Option 1. Addition, 2. Multiplication, 3. Exit");
            string l_strOption = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] l_strNumbers;
            switch (l_strOption)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers seperated by commas.");
                    numbers = Console.ReadLine();
                    l_strNumbers = numbers.Split(',');
                    foreach (string l_strNum in l_strNumbers)
                    {
                        if (double.TryParse(l_strNum, out l_dblRes))
                        {
                            l_dblAnswer += l_dblRes;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers seperated by commas.");
                    numbers = Console.ReadLine();
                    l_strNumbers = numbers.Split(',');
                    foreach (string l_strNum in l_strNumbers)
                    {
                        l_dblAnswer = 1;
                        if (double.TryParse(l_strNum, out l_dblRes))
                        {
                            l_dblAnswer *= l_dblRes;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "3":
                    return;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice.");
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Answer is " + l_dblAnswer.ToString() +           Environment.NewLine);
            Menu();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to do simple math calculator from that menu, but i try put something behind the case 1 it says "control cannot fall through from one case label (case1:) to another

Comment: Use the 'return' keyword to exit your application.

Comment: Check the corrected code.